# About the syntax of Docker build

Tags: linux, docker

I am learning docker at the moment. From https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#text-files, I learnt that the syntax to build an image from a docker file is `docker build - < Dockerfile`. I tried it and it worked, but I am bit confused about the purpose of `-` here. I know that `<` is for redirection, but what does `-` mean here? What does it mean in Linux?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many applications that expect a filename as parameter allow you to specify `-` and use stdin or stdout instead.

In your scenario I would say this only introduces complexity: use the dockerfile directly

Comment: How can I use the dockerfile directly? Like docker build Dockerfile?

Comment: From memory: `docker build .`

Comment: Either that or use `-f`: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#text-files. I can't try it myself atm because my phone doesn't have docker yet ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Many *nix programs interpret a filename argument of `-` to mean "from stdin".  Examples include [`cat`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/cat), [`head`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/head), and [`md5sum`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/md5sum).

It's just a convention, though.  There's no special magic going on here.